# FlutterFlow securities for web

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutterflow

i am building an application for both web and mobile using flutterflow few questions:

FYI: first time mobile developer

1. If my backend is on GCP or AWS , how to implement CORS or other security concerns becuase APIs should be public APIs then only mobile can access it
2. IF it is a public api , how to control bot attacks
3. some where mentioned about authentication but how to handle unauthenicated flow from mobile app
4. how to store secrets in mobile app

any architecture diagram for any application or any book to understand the entire mobile architecture and securities.